# Block based optical flow calculation in opencv c++

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I want to find the optical flow of video whose frames are divided into non overlapping blocks of equal size. How to find the optical flow of each blocks that contains some number of pixels?

I have read `opencv` optical flow functions here https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323 but unfortunately, I don't understand how to use them.

Can someone give me an idea how to implement the block based matching algorithm?